# Python, removing data from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following code in python:

```
data   = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
data_f = data[0::2]
```

**EDIT: Apologies, English is not my first language. I misinterpreted the documentation, and thus posed a question devoid of meaning. I am simply trying to take every second item from a list *data* and put it into _data_f_, so that _data_f_ contains *(1, 3, 5)* and *data* contains *(2, 4, 6)*. How would I get this done if not using pop? (Which I now know does something else)**

Comment: `L.pop([index]) -> item `-- remove and return item at index (default last).
Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range. pop() expects an index and you're passing a slice, so that's not gonna work.

Comment: You should read the document first before posting a question.

Comment: Read the docs, the behavior of pop() is clearly documented. What you think what an API could do is of zero interest. The documentation tells you how a method is actually working. Read the docs instead of guessing.

Comment: `data[1::2]` should give you the `list` you require.

Comment: I am receiving a syntax error - as far as I can tell I am following the syntax laid out in the documentation. I am trying to omit every second number (1, 3, 5) from the list.

Comment: Should we guess what you are trying to accomplish? And which syntax error where and for which code?

Comment: data_f = [data[i] for i in range(len(data)) if i % 2 == 0] This is called a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: print list.pop.__doc__
L.pop([index]) -> item -- remove and return item at index (default last).
Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
```

Note that [index] means that the index is optional, not that it should come as a list.

To remove every second element from a list, you could use a list comprehension:

```
data_f = [data[i] for i in range(len(data))[0::2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you really want to use that syntax, you could do

```
[data.remove(y) for y in data[0::2]]
```

Comment: He tries to omit every second number, not keeping it :)

Comment: I was assuming the above is what he expected data.pop([0::2]) to do. But I guess it is ambiguous.

Comment: Also note that this is very inefficient.